# Force dropdown button contents to overflow containing element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to craft [this HTML/css](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaJeff13/jqpkLaxo/), so that the "Output Sections" dropdown expands the buttons underneath it, without expanding the whitespace that surrounds all the tabs. In other words, I would like the expanded tabs to show, but I don't want the grey content section below them to be pushed down due to the expanding tab container. I've been messing with the `overflow` property but to no avail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Test Run Results</title>
  <style>
    @charset "UTF-8";
    .dropbtn {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: none;
      /* overflow: scroll; */
    }
    
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      /* display: block; */
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
    
    div.sticky {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
    }
    
    pre,
    .pre {
      display: block;
      font-family: monospace;
      white-space: pre;
      margin: 4px 0;
      overflow: auto;
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
      word-break: break-all;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    
    .tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      margin-right: 4px;
    }
    
    .tab button {
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-color: lightgrey;
      border-style;
      border-radius: 2px;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 15px
    }
    
    .tablinks {
      font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px opacity: 0.4;
    }
    
    .tabcontent {
      background-color: #ddd;
      display: none;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-top: none;
      -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
      animation: fadeEffect .25s;
    }
    
    .tabcontent button:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    
    .tabcontent button:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    
    .tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      opacity: 0.65;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .tab button.focus {
      background-color: #ccc;
      opacity: 1.0;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    .tab button.active {
      opacity: 1.0;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    */ @-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      to {
        opacity: .5;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeEffect {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1.5;
      }
    }
    
    .collapsible {
      font-weight: normal;
      font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      padding: 4px 4px;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      white-space: normal;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #bbb;
    }
    
    .active,
    .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #ccc;
      transition: 0.35s;
    }
    
    .content {
      display: none;
      overflow: auto;
      -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
      animation: fadeEffect .25s;
    }
    
    .space {
      width: 4px;
      height: auto;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .line {
      background-color: black;
      height: auto;
      width: 5px;
    }
    
    p {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    }
    
    .body_foreground {
      color: #000000;
    }
    
    .body_background {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="body_foreground body_background" style="font-family: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';">
  <div class="sticky">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.33)" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openTab(event, 'About')">
          About</button
        ><button
          class="tablinks"
          style="background-color: rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.75)"
          onclick="openTab(event, 'Failures')"
        >
          Failures
        </button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" style="color: white; background-color: gray">
            Output Sections
          </button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <p>
            <button class="dropdown-item tablinks" style="background-color: #daeaf6; width: 140px; max-width: 250px" onclick="openTab(event, 'summary_section')">
                summary_section
              </button>
          </p>
          <p>
            <button class="dropdown-item tablinks" style="background-color: rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.50); width: 140px; max-width: 250px" onclick="openTab(event, 'failures_section')">
                failures_section
              </button>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="tablinks" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.33)" onclick="openTab(event, 'Full Output')">
          Full Output
        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="About" class="tabcontent">
    <p></p>
    <hr />
    <h5>Final Results:</h5>
    <pre><b> 1 failed, 62 deselected in 0.96s
</b></pre>
    <hr />
    <h5>Test results generated:</h5>
    <p>2022-09-04 03:11:47</p>
    <h5>This report generated:</h5>
    <p>2022-09-04 03:12:47</p>
    <h5>pytest-tui version:</h5>
    <p>1.3.2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Failures" class="tabcontent">
    <button type="button" class="collapsible" style="border: none; outline: none;">
        demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1
      </button>
    <div class="content">
      <pre>
Test Fail 1!

    def test0_fail_1():
        print("Test Fail 1!")
&gt;       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

demo-tests/test_0.py:37: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------
Test Fail 1!
</pre
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="summary_section" class="tabcontent">
      <pre>
========================================================= 1 failed, 62 deselected in 0.96s ==========================================================

================================================================ test session starts ================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.2.0.dev251+gd9d890ee1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /Users/jwr003/coding/pytest-tui/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.10.5', 'Platform': 'macOS-12.5.1-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'Packages': {'pytest': '7.2.0.dev251+gd9d890ee1', 'py': '1.11.0', 'pluggy': '1.0.0'}, 'Plugins': {'rerunfailures': '10.2', 'html': '3.1.1', 'clarity': '1.0.1', 'Faker': '13.15.1', 'metadata': '2.0.2', 'tui': '1.3.2'}, 'JAVA_HOME': '/Users/jwr003/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.12/Contents/Home'}
rootdir: /Users/jwr003/coding/pytest-tui, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: rerunfailures-10.2, html-3.1.1, clarity-1.0.1, Faker-13.15.1, metadata-2.0.2, tui-1.3.2
collecting ...
collected 63 items / 62 deselected / 1 selected

demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1 FAILED                                                                                                     [100%]

============================================================== short test summary info ==============================================================
FAILED demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1 - assert 1 == 2
</pre
      >
    </div>
    <div id="failures_section" class="tabcontent">
      <pre>
===================================================================== FAILURES ======================================================================
___________________________________________________________________ test0_fail_1 ____________________________________________________________________

    def test0_fail_1():
        print("Test Fail 1!")
&gt;       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

demo-tests/test_0.py:37: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------
Test Fail 1!
</pre
      >
    </div>
    <div id="Full Output" class="tabcontent">
      <pre>
================================================================ test session starts ================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.2.0.dev251+gd9d890ee1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /Users/jwr003/coding/pytest-tui/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.10.5', 'Platform': 'macOS-12.5.1-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'Packages': {'pytest': '7.2.0.dev251+gd9d890ee1', 'py': '1.11.0', 'pluggy': '1.0.0'}, 'Plugins': {'rerunfailures': '10.2', 'html': '3.1.1', 'clarity': '1.0.1', 'Faker': '13.15.1', 'metadata': '2.0.2', 'tui': '1.3.2'}, 'JAVA_HOME': '/Users/jwr003/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.12/Contents/Home'}
rootdir: /Users/jwr003/coding/pytest-tui, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: rerunfailures-10.2, html-3.1.1, clarity-1.0.1, Faker-13.15.1, metadata-2.0.2, tui-1.3.2
collecting ...
collected 63 items / 62 deselected / 1 selected

demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1 FAILED                                                                                                     [100%]

===================================================================== FAILURES ======================================================================
___________________________________________________________________ test0_fail_1 ____________________________________________________________________

    def test0_fail_1():
        print("Test Fail 1!")
&gt;       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

demo-tests/test_0.py:37: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------
Test Fail 1!
============================================================== short test summary info ==============================================================
FAILED demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1 - assert 1 == 2
========================================================= 1 failed, 62 deselected in 0.96s ==========================================================
</pre
      >
    </div>
    <script>
      function openTab(evt, tabName) { var i, tabcontent, tablinks; tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent"); for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) { tabcontent[i].style.display = "none"; } tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks"); for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) { tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", ""); } document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block"; evt.currentTarget.className += " active"; }
    </script>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
    </script>
    <script>
      var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible"); var i; for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) { coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() { this.classList.toggle("active"); var content = this.nextElementSibling; if (content.style.display === "block") { content.style.display = "none"; } else { content.style.display = "block"; } }); }
    </script>
    <script>
      /* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */ function myFunction() { document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show"); }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just brought your code here, so it will be reproducible now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these styles with some explanation

```
.tab {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/ /*Remove this to create an overlay on menu items*/
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative; /*Keep sub-menu aligned with the main menu item*/
  display: inline-block;
  /* display: block; */
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; /*Overlay for sub-menu items*/
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 47px; /*Top gap with the main item*/
}

.dropdown-content p {
   margin: 0; /*Removed useless gaps on sub-menu items*/
}
```

The key factor is removing `overflow: hidden` in `.tab` and using `position: absolute` on `.dropdown-content`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test Run Results</title>
    <style>
      @charset "UTF-8";

      .dropbtn {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        /* overflow: scroll; */
      }

      .dropdown {
        position: relative; /*Keep sub-menu aligned with the main menu item*/
        display: inline-block;
        /* display: block; */
      }

      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute; /*Overlay for sub-menu items*/
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 1;
        top: 47px; /*Top gap with the main item*/
      }

      .dropdown-content p {
        margin: 0; /*Removed useless gaps on sub-menu items*/
      }

      .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
      }

      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
      }

      div.sticky {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      }

      pre,
      .pre {
        display: block;
        font-family: monospace;
        white-space: pre;
        margin: 4px 0;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        word-break: break-all;
        word-wrap: break-word;
      }

      .tab {
        /*overflow: hidden;*/ /*Remove this to create an overlay on menu items*/
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        margin-right: 4px;
      }

      .tab button {
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: inherit;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-color: lightgrey;
        border-style;
        border-radius: 2px;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        font-size: 15px
      }

      .tablinks {
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px opacity: 0.4;
      }

      .tabcontent {
        background-color: #ddd;
        display: none;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top: none;
        -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
        animation: fadeEffect .25s;
      }

      .tabcontent button:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #ddd;
      }

      .tabcontent button:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }

      .tab button:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        opacity: 0.65;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .tab button.focus {
        background-color: #ccc;
        opacity: 1.0;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      .tab button.active {
        opacity: 1.0;
        transition: 0.3s;
      }

      */ @-webkit-keyframes fadeEffect {
        from {
          opacity: 0;
        }

        to {
          opacity: .5;
        }
      }

      @keyframes fadeEffect {
        from {
          opacity: 0;
        }

        to {
          opacity: 1.5;
        }
      }

      .collapsible {
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        padding: 4px 4px;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        white-space: normal;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #bbb;
      }

      .active,
      .collapsible:hover {
        background-color: #ccc;
        transition: 0.35s;
      }

      .content {
        display: none;
        overflow: auto;
        -webkit-animation: fadeEffect 1s;
        animation: fadeEffect .25s;
      }

      .space {
        width: 4px;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .line {
        background-color: black;
        height: auto;
        width: 5px;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
      }

      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6 {
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
      }

      .body_foreground {
        color: #000000;
      }

      .body_background {
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="body_foreground body_background" style="font-family: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';">
    <div class="sticky">
      <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.33)" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openTab(event, 'About')">
          About</button><button class="tablinks" style="background-color: rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.75)" onclick="openTab(event, 'Failures')">
          Failures
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn" style="color: white; background-color: gray">
            Output Sections
          </button>
          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <p>
              <button class="dropdown-item tablinks" style="background-color: #daeaf6; width: 140px; max-width: 250px" onclick="openTab(event, 'summary_section')">
                summary_section
              </button>
            </p>
            <p>
              <button class="dropdown-item tablinks" style="background-color: rgba(255, 10, 10, 0.50); width: 140px; max-width: 250px" onclick="openTab(event, 'failures_section')">
                failures_section
              </button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="tablinks" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.33)" onclick="openTab(event, 'Full Output')">
          Full Output
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="About" class="tabcontent">
      <p></p>
      <hr />
      <h5>Final Results:</h5>
      <pre><b> 1 failed, 62 deselected in 0.96s
</b></pre>
      <hr />
      <h5>Test results generated:</h5>
      <p>2022-09-04 03:11:47</p>
      <h5>This report generated:</h5>
      <p>2022-09-04 03:12:47</p>
      <h5>pytest-tui version:</h5>
      <p>1.3.2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Failures" class="tabcontent">
      <button type="button" class="collapsible" style="border: none; outline: none;">
        demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1
      </button>
      <div class="content">
        <pre>
Test Fail 1!

    def test0_fail_1():
        print("Test Fail 1!")
&gt;       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

demo-tests/test_0.py:37: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------
Test Fail 1!
</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="summary_section" class="tabcontent">
      <pre>
========================================================= 1 failed, 62 deselected in 0.96s ==========================================================

================================================================ test session starts ================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.2.0.dev251+gd9d890ee1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /Users/jwr003/coding/pytest-tui/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.10.5', 'Platform': 'macOS-12.5.1-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'Packages': {'pytest': '7.2.0.dev251+gd9d890ee1', 'py': '1.11.0', 'pluggy': '1.0.0'}, 'Plugins': {'rerunfailures': '10.2', 'html': '3.1.1', 'clarity': '1.0.1', 'Faker': '13.15.1', 'metadata': '2.0.2', 'tui': '1.3.2'}, 'JAVA_HOME': '/Users/jwr003/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.12/Contents/Home'}
rootdir: /Users/jwr003/coding/pytest-tui, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: rerunfailures-10.2, html-3.1.1, clarity-1.0.1, Faker-13.15.1, metadata-2.0.2, tui-1.3.2
collecting ...
collected 63 items / 62 deselected / 1 selected

demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1 FAILED                                                                                                     [100%]

============================================================== short test summary info ==============================================================
FAILED demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1 - assert 1 == 2
</pre>
    </div>
    <div id="failures_section" class="tabcontent">
      <pre>
===================================================================== FAILURES ======================================================================
___________________________________________________________________ test0_fail_1 ____________________________________________________________________

    def test0_fail_1():
        print("Test Fail 1!")
&gt;       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

demo-tests/test_0.py:37: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------
Test Fail 1!
</pre>
    </div>
    <div id="Full Output" class="tabcontent">
      <pre>
================================================================ test session starts ================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.2.0.dev251+gd9d890ee1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /Users/jwr003/coding/pytest-tui/venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.10.5', 'Platform': 'macOS-12.5.1-x86_64-i386-64bit', 'Packages': {'pytest': '7.2.0.dev251+gd9d890ee1', 'py': '1.11.0', 'pluggy': '1.0.0'}, 'Plugins': {'rerunfailures': '10.2', 'html': '3.1.1', 'clarity': '1.0.1', 'Faker': '13.15.1', 'metadata': '2.0.2', 'tui': '1.3.2'}, 'JAVA_HOME': '/Users/jwr003/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.12/Contents/Home'}
rootdir: /Users/jwr003/coding/pytest-tui, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: rerunfailures-10.2, html-3.1.1, clarity-1.0.1, Faker-13.15.1, metadata-2.0.2, tui-1.3.2
collecting ...
collected 63 items / 62 deselected / 1 selected

demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1 FAILED                                                                                                     [100%]

===================================================================== FAILURES ======================================================================
___________________________________________________________________ test0_fail_1 ____________________________________________________________________

    def test0_fail_1():
        print("Test Fail 1!")
&gt;       assert 1 == 2
E       assert 1 == 2

demo-tests/test_0.py:37: AssertionError
--------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------------------------------------
Test Fail 1!
============================================================== short test summary info ==============================================================
FAILED demo-tests/test_0.py::test0_fail_1 - assert 1 == 2
========================================================= 1 failed, 62 deselected in 0.96s ==========================================================
</pre>
    </div>
    <script>
      function openTab(evt, tabName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
          tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
          tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
      }

    </script>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

    </script>
    <script>
      var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
          }
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script>
      /* When the user clicks on the button, toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Beautiful. I'll see if I can adapt these changes to my larger codebase, but this looks very promising. Thanks!

Comment: Accepting your  answer, Nick. Thanks again!